# Change fixed position on click

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm going to try make it clear:

I have a mobile menu with media queries and a header fixed on mobile. The situation is the customer want the header (with logo) fixed on top, but when I try to expand the menu item (like Menu > SubMenu > Submenu) it expand vertically but I can not scroll to bottom (the page is scrolling behind it, but not the menu). So I figured out how to make it work: When the site loads the header is fixed, but when someone tries to use the top menu, they must click on the hamburger menu and (this what I want you to help me), and when they click on the hamburger menu the header should pass from `position:fixed` to `position:static`, just then the mobile menu will scroll down as I want.

Here the site: http://centro.anden.pe

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you mind giving a current code example? What does your layout look like?

Comment: In fact I was trying to put the site online and making a gif (to come).

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: If you put `position: static` on the nav after you fixed it to the top of the screen, it will no longer be visible. The `position:static` will put it in the page where it used to be, and you won't be able to see it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't attached code, but here's a functional example of that idea (click on the hamburguer menu)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
      $("#hamburguer_menu").on("click", function() {
        $("#change-div-if-click").css("background-color", "yellow")
        $("#change-div-if-click").css("position", "static")
        alert ('now the position is static')
      });
      
    
    });
```

```css
#hamburguer_menu {
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    #change-div-if-click {
      background-color: teal;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
    <body>
    
    <div id="hamburguer_menu">
      <img src="https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/tupix-1/30/list-512.png" / height="60px" width="60px">
    </div>
    
    <div id="change-div-if-click">
      <p>Change when clicked</p>
    </div>
    
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you Miguel. I'm going to test it right now. I'll let you know how it's going.